# silverlight runtime contextmenu

Tags: silverlight, runtime, contextmenu

the Question is that, is it possible to have a silverlight context menu in runtime (which its menu items can be manipulated, ie added or removed in runtime)?
as I searched, there are some types of adding Context menu in silverlight by xaml, But I didn' found any solution to add it in runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

ContextMenuItem item1 = new ContextMenuItem();
item1.Content = "新建";

ContextMenuItem item2 = new ContextMenuItem();
item2.Content = "保存":

menu.Items.Add(item1);
menu.Items.Add(item2);
```

Comment: May My Question Is not comlete! please explain how shoud I access its items click event. thanks a lot. my another question is that I have no ContextMentItem in my VS2012,why?!

Answer (score 0):

ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();

MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();

item1.Header = "new";

item1.Click +=new RoutedEventHandler(item1_Click);

menu.Items.Add(item1);

you can use ↓
Telerik provide RadControl for SilveLight

RadMenu menu = new RadMenu();

RadMenuItem item1 = new RadMenuItem();

RadMenuItem item1_01 = new RadMenuItem();

item.Items.add(item1_01);

menu.Items.Add(item);

no matter RadMenu or RadMenuItem or ContextMenu ,

你都可以添加事件，他们都是继承与Sytem.window.Control;

forgive ^_^